# Como ler dados em Json no servidor?

Tags: c#, json

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC e estou tentando reaproveitar uma Action que retorna Json dentro do servidor, mas não estou conseguindo trabalhar com retornos em Json em C#.

Estou realizando pesquisas, mas não encontrei nada que me ajude até o momento.

Trecho do código:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(int param) 
{ 

   var minhaListaDeObjetos = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3};

   return Json(new 
      { 
        success = true, 
        data = minhaListaDeObjetos 
      }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Em outra Action tenho:

```
var resultado = MinhaAction(param);
```

Como acessar os dados dentro de `resultado`?

Tenho tentado assim:

```
resultado.data.minhaListaDeObjeto.First();
```

O resultado deveria ser `1`, mas essa linha não funciona.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esta é a maneira bem errada de fazer. *Actions* devem retornar valores apenas a requisições, e não a funções internas.

A maneira correta de fazer isso é através de *Helpers*, classes estáticas que servem justamente ao propósito de serem reutilizadas. Por exemplo:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(int param) 
{ 
   // Vamos passar isto para um Helper
   // var minhaListaDeObjetos = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3};
   var minhaListaDeObjetos = MeuHelper.TrazerLista();

   return Json(new 
      { 
        success = true, 
        data = minhaListaDeObjetos 
      }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

O *Helper* fica:

```
public static class MeuHelper 
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> TrazerLista()
    {
        return new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
}
```

Você não precisa fazer JSON circular por dentro do código C# porque JSON não é uma estrutura de dados do C#. É uma estrutura que é serializada para um retorno em algum momento.

Listas e dicionários cumprem melhor esta função.